# Does this matrix operation obey the rule of matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

I want to let $\vec y$ become $\vec u_b \ \rho_b \ \vec y $ and $\vec u_c \ \rho_c \ \vec y $, after a series matrix multiplication,but i am not sure if my matrix multiplication is right or not.

$$
    \mathbf u \mathbf \rho \mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix}
    \vec u_b & 0 \\
    0 & \vec u_c \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \rho_b & 0 \\
    0 & \rho_c \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \vec y & 0 \\
    0 & \vec y \\
    \end{bmatrix}=    \begin{bmatrix}
    \vec u_b \rho_b \vec y & 0 \\
    0 & \vec u_c \rho_c \vec y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is this calculation right?If it is wrong,how do i improve it?
I usually multiply the matrix whose elements are all scalar,but now their element are scalar and vector,so i am not sure this is right or wrong

By the way,$\vec u_b$ and $\vec u_c$ are $1$ by $N$ vector
,$\rho_b$ and $\rho_c$ are both scalar,$\vec y$ is a $N$ by $1$ matrix

$\mathbf u$ is $2$ by $N+1$ matrix,and  $\mathbf y$ is $N+1$ by $2$ matrix.

It seems that there is something wrong,but i don't know how to improve this

Comment: Your $U$ matrix is actually $2\times N$ and $Y$ matrix is $N\times 2$. You can achieve the desired result by pre or post multiplying by your $\rho$ matrix. I.e. $\rho UY$ or $UY\rho$. If you desire for the product $U\rho Y$, you need $\rho=\begin{bmatrix}\rho_bI_N&0\\0&\rho_cI_N\end{bmatrix}$, where $I_N$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix.

Comment: @Daryl So if i improve the $\rho$ like you said,my result can become what i want,i mean i can get $ \vec u_b \ \rho_b \vec y $ and  $ \vec u_c \ \rho_c \vec y $ ?

Comment: Yes. That’s right.